# Como faço o transition funcionar na "ida e na volta" ao usar hover?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-transições, css-hover

Tenho esse `:hover` aqui...

```
.novidades{
  background-color: #F5dcdc;
  background-color: #f5dcdc;
  background: linear-gradient(#f5dcdc, #bebef4);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

.novidades:hover{
  bottom: 20px;
  transition: bottom 0.4s ease;
}
```

Como eu faço pro bloco `.novidades` voltar em animação `ease` para o mesmo lugar, ao invés de ser "teletransportado" para o lugar original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ponha a `transition` no objeto original, e não no `:hover`:

```css
.novidades{
  display:block; height:100px; width:200px; /* só pra demonstrar */
  background-color: #f5dcdc;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.4s ease; /* passamos a transition para cá*/
}
.novidades:hover{
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="novidades">Novidades</div>
```